# JQuery and ASP.net with DIV

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML table in jQuery.several rows avail in that HTML table.in that table i appended div in first TD.the first TD have text box.the default display of div is none.when am entering value into first TD the div id value=value entered first TD textbox value.like this how i append/assign div id value after entering first TD in HTML Table..... Am new one to JQuery

```
$items = $items + '<td width="16px" ><img onclick="pop(this);" id="imgpop" width="16px" style="cursor: pointer;" height="16px" src="../Images/plus.gif" /><input type="text" style="width:80%;" class="mtextbox" autocomplete="off" onfocus="FnAutocomNo(this, \'FWHSortCode\',1);" onblur="createRow(this);" name="txtSortCode" id="txtSortCode" />'; $items = $items + '<input type="hidden" name="hdnSortId" id="hdnSortId" />'; $items = $items + ' <div id="popDiv1" class="menu" style="display:none;"><table id="popup1"><tr><td colspan="10"></td></tr></table></div></td>';
```

Comment: Can you show the script that you have used..?

Comment: its to long how can i post that code

Comment: Post the relevant code..

Comment: Just put a useful part of html and script.

Comment: $items = $items + '<td width="16px" ><img onclick="pop(this);"   id="imgpop" width="16px" style="cursor: pointer;" height="16px" src="../Images/plus.gif" /><input type="text" style="width:80%;" class="mtextbox" autocomplete="off"  onfocus="FnAutocomNo(this, \'FWHSortCode\',1);" onblur="createRow(this);" name="txtSortCode" id="txtSortCode"  />';
             $items = $items + '<input type="hidden" name="hdnSortId" id="hdnSortId" />';

             $items = $items + ' <div id="popDiv1" class="menu" style="display:none;"><table id="popup1"><tr><td colspan="10"></td></tr></table></div></td>';

Comment: not here. In the question. [Check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: or else u give idea of how to assign runtime entered textbox value to DIV id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need ..! [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/koushikKumar/E4XJt/2/)
**HTML :**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="divid"></div>
                <input id="inputid" type="text"></input>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#inputid").on('keyup',function(){

        $("#divid").text($(this).val());
    });

});
```

Comment: thanks Kamesh,but i used only one DIV it come's in repeat manner.for example i have 3 textbox based on the text box values i need to create 3 different DIV using only one DIV.